# Amazon Pay integration -Web

Tags: coldfusion-11, amazon-pay

Would like to integrate the amazon pay in the application(US based). Already having paypal and pay by card option.
When referred for amazon pay sandbox, it says to register in amazon pay first. The registration process is taken to amazon seller center account other steps where business related questions are asked.

In development point of view, how can we integrate the amazon pay to our application? Is there any sample api/code available and its procedures?
Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation on developer.amazon.com is a good starting point for the integration. The following link points to the US version of the documentation and provides links for the integration into websites and Alexa skills:

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay/intro.html

It also provides links to additional developers resources such as API Reference Guides, SDKs and sample code:

[image: Developer Resources]

Comment: Thank you Daniel Lemke.  From the above guide, found the reference https://amzn.github.io/amazon-pay-sdk-samples/login_and_pay/lpa-login.html. It mentioned about getting sandbox view as 'select "Amazon Pay (Sandbox View)" from the picklist at the top of the screen' . Could not find the sandbox navigation from seller central. Is there any procedures to see the sandbox link?

Comment: No, this should be available in the small drop down box as "Amazon Pay (Sandbox View)" that you can find on top of the page after log in. 

If you see the drop down box, but no entry for Amazon Pay, it's probably not a Amazon Pay Seller Central account that you are logged in with, or you haven't completed the registration process properly yet. For the registration of a US Amazon Pay merchant account, please go here:
https://pay.amazon.com/signup

Comment: Thanks,completed the registration process and now the sandbox option is visible. Is there cancellation procedures similar to paypal void for amazon pay? If the customer who used amazon pay on our website want to cancel the order, then what will be the steps? The document seems to say "After initiating a payment, Amazon Pay can't cancel it."

Comment: Created test account. While going through the samples, 
https://amzn.github.io/amazon-pay-sdk-samples/, it mention about two variations -
Amazon pay and Simple checkout. 
What is the difference between them?